# Are bit permutations linear?

Tags: linear-algebra, permutations, cryptography

I'm trying to answer a question on cryptography.

Basically, inputs and outputs (so plaintexts and ciphertexts) are from the set (say) $\{0, 1\}^{100}$. The encryption function takes inputs and splits them up into 50 bits each, messes around with them, then reassembles them into the 100-bit output. The key (that is used for encrypting) is from a larger set, say $\{0, 1 \}^{204}$, and the cryptosystem is linear in the key (in other words, the only action the key really does is $\oplus$, obviously with subections of the key of size 50). The only other weird thing about the cipher is that, when encrypting, parts are permuted with the fixed permutation $P\colon\{0,1\}^{50} \mapsto \{0, 1\}^{50}$. My question is this:

Does it follow that we only need 3 pairs of messages with corresponding ciphertext? IE, the first pair gives us 100 linear equations in 203 unknowns, two pairs gives us 200 linear equations in 203 unknown and after 3 pairs we're done (so long as the plaintexts are all different)? It depends on whether $P$ is linear doesn't it? does this question even really make sense?

Comment: When you write "we need only 3 pairs of messages" -- do you need those _for what_? Recovering the key?

Answer (score 1):

Permutations are linear maps. Here's why:

Think of the bit strings as forming a vector space over the integers mod 2, say with basis $e_0,e_1,\ldots$. To illustrate let's assume the dimension is 3, so
$$101=e_0+e_2$$
$$011=e_0+e_1$$
etc. Let's say the permutation maps $012\mapsto 201$. Then what we are doing is permuting basis vectors. The matrix for the corresponding linear transformation is
$$A=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}0&0&1\\1&0&0\\0&1&0\end{array}\right)$$
Hence
$$A((e_0+e_2)+(e_0+e_1))=(e_2+e_1)+(e_2+e_0)=e_0+e_1=A(e_1+e_2)$$
To generalize this example, the linear transformation corresponding to application of a permutation can be represented by the corresponding permutation matrix permuting the basis vectors.